# getting source code of a compiled class

Tags: java, encryption, netbeans

I am using netbeans and programming in Java.

There is a class Cipher with function doFinal(), I press Ctrl and go into the source code of the class but all I get is " //compiled code"

How can I see the source  code ? do I need to attach complete src folder ?

Is there a simpler way ?

Thanks

Comment: Try using IntelliJ, it's decompiler has never failed me

Comment: *"How can I see the source code ? do I need to attach complete src folder ?"* - That is the best approach.

Comment: @JohnD that will be my last option, addicted with netbeans, cant leave it as well :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use this http://jd.benow.ca/ to decompiler the source code then you can check it whenever you want.